# XNA - Grid overlay too prominent

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

I am trying to create a grid overlay for my "terrain".

Currently I am using a linelist to create my grid lines that I currently have.

However to stop from z-depth fighting, I had to set the depthBais to 1.

As you can see in the first picture the grid lines get less prominent the further distance they are from the camera. However from what I tried to do my lines are very prominent.

How would one go about reducing the prominence of the grid lines the further away they are?

Desired Result:
[image: Desired Result]

Actual Result
[image: Actual Result]

Comment: Just noticed the second picture has much more anti aliasing. *May* help the situation a bit. `graphics.PreferMultiSampling = true;` and `graphics.ApplyChanges()`

Comment: It helped make the picture sharper however it made the distance completely red, so helped a different issue, thanks :)

Comment: Well I'm no good at these 3D things, glad I could help a bit though :)

Comment: Me either, fumbling my way. haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought. Something you may want to try is to simply change the alpha value of your grid lines to decrease the further they are drawn away from the camera. By doing so, you should see the color of the square instead of the line. I'm not sure if this will look like what you want, but you should at least see gray and white instead of red.

If you are not aware, you can an easily modify an XNA color with a float alpha transparency with the following code.

```
Color gridColor = Color.White * AlphaValue;
```

or you can use the float based [color constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433805%28v=xnagamestudio.35%29.aspx).

```
public Color(float r, float g, float b, float a)
```

Comment: Is there some equation that comes to mind that would suit this change in alpha depending on the difference in distance? Or should i just play around with it

Comment: Nvm just used pythagorean to find the difference and did 1/difference, worked well. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent and your welcome. I'm glad this worked well for you. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy way is a pixel shader, but if you don't want shaders, I think the solution is working in screen space for this.

If you have a line list, each line has two vertices in 3D.

I would project each vertice of the line to screen space, (2D coords), then I had a 2D line.

Now would be time of cut the line to begin and end in the screen edges or inside its bounds.

Then calculate the alpha based in height.

1. 1 : height == Screen height
2. 0 : height < Skyline height

Maybe that will be needed to divide the line in two, the first part is visible and the second part is completely hidden.

Then you draw the line with a 2D camera setting or unproject the vertices to 3D.

[image]